# Attempt to render state value from ajax call in componentDidMount failing (React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, reactjs, state

I've made an AJAX call in React with Axios, and I'm a bit confused about how the response is dealt with.

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then( res => {
         const users = res.data
         this.setState({ users });
      });
}

render() {
   console.log(this.state.users)  
   return (
   <div>
      {this.state.users.map( user => <p>{user.name}</p>)}
   </div>
   )
}
```

When I console.log the results, two values are returned:

1. `[]` - the empty array assigned to the initial state
2. The expected array from the API.

This presumably can be explained by the state value being returned once on initialisation, and then again with componentDidMount.

My problem arises in how I access the `this.state.users` value. Obviously any time I access this, I want the values returned from the AJAX response, but if, for example I try to render the `name` property from the first object in the array...

`{this.state.users[0].name}`

...it attempts to access `[]`, and thus returns nothing.

However, if I try to iterate through the arrays elements...

`{users.map( user => <p>user.name</p> )}`

...it returns the values as expected.

I don't know why it works with the second example but not the first. Surely if the first is attempting to pull data from the initial state value (an empty array), then when *mapping* through `this.state.users` it would also be attempting to map through an empty array and return nothing, or an error.

I'm obviously not fully understanding the React rendering process here and how componentDidMount works in the component lifecycle. Am I wrong in trying to assign the response value directly to state?

Would appreciate if anyone could help to clear this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `map()` on `this.state.users` initially, it will do so over an empty array (which won't render anything). Once the response arrives, and `this.setState({ users })` is called, `render()` will run again. This time, the array of users is no longer empty and the `map()` operation will be performed on each of the users in the array.

However, when you use `{this.state.users[0].name}` initially on the empty array, you're trying to access the `name` property of an object that doesn't yet exist — which will result in an error. To prevent the error, you could do a check before accessing the properties of the object:

```
{this.state.users.length > 0 && this.state.users[0].name}
```

Now it will behave the same way as in the first example. I.e. the first `render()` won't actually do anything, since `this.state.users.length = 0`. But as soon as `this.setState()` is called with new users, `render()` will run again, and this time `this.state.users[0].name` is available.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. It still feels a bit of a 'hacky' way to access the data somehow, but if it works it works I guess :)

Comment: I actually don't think it's hacky at all, but you could do this in numerous ways. One way is to pull out the user like this: `firstUser = this.state.users[0] || {}`. Then `{firstUser.name}` at least won't give you an error. Personally though, I prefer the first alternative.

Comment: Ok, that's a good alternative, thanks. I think I'm probably just not used to the React way of doing things - the advantages of having different lifecycle stages of component rendering probably cancels out any minor drawbacks of having to provide conditional statements to render the state value.

Comment: Trying to access `this.state.users[0].name`, when the array is empty, would result in an error regardless of React. It's really just a JS error. I think the confusion might be more about ajax being asynchronous. If you don't want the component to render until it has received the data, you could return null, a loading spinner, etc, until the data is there.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way with constructor. just add your state with empty array users as-

```
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         users: []
      };
   }
```

With this component first rendered with empty users array. When you trigger state update, component rerender with new array.

Comment: Sorry, my code snippet didn't include that - that's how I rendered the empty array to being with.